# How to stop increasing a turtle variable once it reaches some maximum value?

Tags: netlogo

Hi I need help in NetLogo variable settings.

I have turtles that own attributes with range of values, that is the minimum and the maximum.

```
turtles-own [weight history state-turtles run-duration ek tt cu sp]

to setup-turtles
  create- NMAs 2 [ 
  set ek 8 ; range 8 to 9
  set tt 5 ;range 5 to 7
  set cu 3 ; range 3 to 5
  set sp 4 ; range 4 to 7
 ]
create- NBSs 2 [
 set ek 3 ; range 3 to 5
 set tt 4 ; range 4 to 7
 set cu 3 ; range 3 to 4
 set sp 3 ; range 3 to 6
]
to setup-patches 
ask patches [ let projects random 4
 ;setup colours
 ]
End
to go
 tick
 ask turtles [
......
 ]
 search-patch
 if .....
]
End
to search-patch
  if ( [ pcolor ] of patch-here = brown ) [ 
ifelse (;statement) [
update-turtles
 ] [
action-turtles 
]
]
end
to update-turtles
if pcolor = yellow [
 set ek ek + 0.1 
 set tt tt + 0.5 
 set cu cu + 0.1
 set sp sp + 1 ]
 if pcolor = green [
 set ek ......
```

The numbers are kept increasing and I want to set up limits (range) as shown in setup turtles for each attribute Thank you

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your question. Can you try again to explain, step by step, exactly what you want to happen? (You can edit your question to improve it.)

Answer (score 0):

```
turtles-own [... ek-max tt-max cu-max sp-max ...]

to setup
  ...
  create-NMAs 2 [
    set ek 8
    set ek-max 9
    ...
  ]
  ...
end

to update-turtles
  ...
  if ek + 0.1 <= ek-max [ set ek ek + 0.1 ]
  if tt + 0.5 <= tt-max [ set tt tt + 0.5 ]
  if cu + 0.1 <= cu-max [ set cu cu + 0.1 ]
  if sp + 1   <= sp-max [ set sp sp + 1   ]
  ...
end
```

As a side note, `tick` should come at the end of your `go` procedure, not at the beginning ([reference](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#ticks)).